# How is this value calculated?

Tags: c, struct

This is from a past paper at university.

There's a `struct` initialised:

```
struct double {int value; struct * double pred; struct * double succ;};
```

Then in the main function:

```
main(...)
{
    struct double * d1, * d2, * d3;
    d1 = newDouble(33);
    d2 = newDouble(55);
    d3 = newDouble(77);
    d1 -> succ = d2;
    d2 -> pred = d1;
    d2 -> succ = d3;
    d3 -> pred = d2;

    printf("%d/n", d1->succ->succ->pred->value); // ??
}
```

What I don't understand is what the `->` does in `printf`. I can't work out what the value would actually be.

Comment: It's doing the exact same in the printf as in the earlier examples

Comment: `d1` contains a pointer to `d2` which contains a pointer to `d3` they also contain pointers to the struct that contains them so it goes from d1 to d2 to d3 back to d2 so the value should be 55 (i think)

Comment: Don't ever name a struct `double`, that's extremely confusing since `double` is also a primitive floating-point type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` is dereferencing the pointers to access fields: `d1->succ` is shorthand for `(*d1).succ`.

With this convoluted construction: `d1->succ->succ->pred->value`, you'll end up with the value of `d2`, presumably `55`:

- `d1->succ` is `d2`.
- So `d1->succ->succ` is equivalent to `d2->succ`, which is `d3`.
- So `d1->succ->succ->pred` is equivalent to `d3->pred`, which is `d2`.
- So `d1->succ->succ->pred->value` is equivalent to `d2->value`.

Answer (score 1):

`a->b` in C is equal to `(*a).b`.

This means, you will dereference pointer `a`, and get the `b` member of the struct it points to.

In this example, `d1->succ` is `d2` and therefore `d1->succ->succ` is equal to `d2->succ`, which is `d3`. Continuing on, `d1->succ->succ->pred` is `d2->succ->prev` which is `d3->prev` which is `d2`. In the end, `d1->succ->succ->pred->value` is `d2->value`, which is `55`.